# converting Sklearn based custom metric function -> to use as Keras' metric for callbacks

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

I have already been given a custom metric code on which my model is going to be evaluated but they've used `sklearn's` metrices. I know If I have a metric I can use it in callbacks like

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy', custom_metric])


ModelCheckpoint(monitor='val_custom_metric',
                save_best_only=True,
                save_weights_only=True,
                mode='max',
                verbose=1)
```

It is a multi-output problem with 3 labels,

**Submissions are evaluated using a hierarchical macro-averaged recall. First, a standard macro-averaged recall is calculated for each component (label_1,label_2 or label_3). The final score is the weighted average of those three scores, with the `label_1` given double weight. You can replicate the metric with the following python snippet:**

and I am unable to comprehend how do I implement the code given below in keras-

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.metrics

scores = []
for component in ['label_1', 'label_2', 'label_3']:
    y_true_subset = solution[solution[component] == component]['target'].values
    y_pred_subset = submission[submission[component] == component]['target'].values
    scores.append(sklearn.metrics.recall_score(
        y_true_subset, y_pred_subset, average='macro'))
final_score = np.average(scores, weights=[2,1,1])
```

How can I convert it in the form to use as a metric? or more preciely, how can I use `keras.backend` or to implement this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can only implement the metric, the rest is very obscure and will certainly not participate in Keras.

```
threshold = 0.5 #you can work this threshold for better results


#considering y_true is made of 0 and 1 only
#considering output shape is (batch, 3)
def custom_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    weights = K.constant([2,1,1]) #shape (3,)

    y_pred = K.cast(K.greater(y_pred, threshold), K.floatx()) #shape (batch, 3)
    true_positives = K.sum(y_pred * y_true, axis=0)  #shape (3,)
    false_negatives = K.sum((1-y_pred) * y_true, axis=0) #shape (3,)

    recall = true_positives / (true_positives + false_negatives)
    return K.mean(recall * weights)
```

Notice that this will be calulated batchwise, and since the denominator is different depending on the results, the calculated metric batchwise will be different compared to when you use the metric for the entire dataset.

You may need big batch sizes to avoid metric instability. And it might be interesting to apply the metric on the entire data with a callback to get the exact result.